# Manage complex json response

Tags: javascript, json

Let me give you an idea what I am doing. Actually I am working on neo4j and d3 libraries. I got the response from neo4j in json and trying to use that response in d3.js

But I faced a very complex json response which is out of my boundaries. As I am new to programming.
Here is my json code :

```
{"results":[{"columns":["p"],"data":[{"row":[[{"aNumber":"3214235014"},{},{"bNumber":"3212820572"}]],"meta":[[{"id":1678,"type":"node","deleted":false},{"id":914,"type":"relationship","deleted":false},{"id":994,"type":"node","deleted":false}]]}]}],"errors":[]}
```

From this response I need value of aNumber,bNumber,id,type and deleted
I have gone this far `console.log(data.results[0].data);` BUT unable to go further down in `row` and `meta` array, How can I get the values from this json ??

Comment: first try it, second try again, thid put te code you've done, and will help you

Comment: Just try something, it's not a so "complex" json response. As long as the response is linear, the answer is easy. Just give some tries, and keep in mind that data is an array of rows, which is an array of array of objects, so you likely need to loop each row, and, out of each element of the row, get the **index** of the **desired object**. Logically, for "aNumber", it's something like: row->element[0].aNumber

Comment: when faced to this, organize your thoughts: decompose the object with new lines in an editor so that structure is more readable. Then go step by step, if a `[` you need to add `[indexWanted]`, if you have a `{` just add `.propertyWanted`

Comment: well, that's good advice's from all of you. I will try to simplify the response and will get the required result. Thanks

Comment: It helps to display the JSON in a formatted way. Use any of the beautifiers that exist online, or output the object you got from the response (after interpreting the response as a JavaScript object) with `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)`. That should help to grab the structure you are dealing with.

Comment: I have used `console.log(data.results[0].data[0].row[0][0].aNumber);` for my final result. Of course I will put it into loop to get all values. Thought I should post here

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` property is an array, you should access to the child object like this :

```
data.results[0].data[0].row

data.results[0].data[0].meta
```